# admingrid in Magento-2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I have mention below template file for faq.But it throws all html tags in frontend.How to remove this? If It is correct way use escapeHtml in template file.Is it neccessary or not?

```
<?php
    $collectionTitle = $this->getCollectionTitle();
    ?>
    <div id="element" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": false, "multipleCollapsible": true}}'> 
        <?php foreach ($collectionTitle as $item): ?>  
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <div data-role="trigger"> 
                    <span>
                        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($item->getCategoryName()); ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>    

            <?php $collection = $this->getCollection($item->getId()); ?> 
            <div data-role="content">
                <?php foreach ($collection as $items): ?>             
                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($items->getQuestion()); ?> 
                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($items->getAnswer()); ?>            
                <?php endforeach; ?> 
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

**Layout file**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>FAQs</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Xxx\Faqs\Block\Faq\Collection" name="footerLink" template="Xxx_Faqs::view.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: create a new phtml file and try  ti again

Comment: Post your layout code!

Comment: updated my post

Comment: nothing change it @Amit Bera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Vendor\Faq\Block\Faq\Collection"> <!-- change name here to match your block class name -->
        <arguments>
            <argument name="templateProcessor" xsi:type="object">Magento\Widget\Model\Template\Filter</argument>
        </arguments>
</type>
```

In `Vendor\Faq\Block\Faq\Collection.php` define `filterOutputHtml()` function like below :

```
   public function __construct(
    ....
        \Zend_Filter_Interface $templateProcessor,
        array $data = array()
    ) {    
    ...
        $this->templateProcessor = $templateProcessor;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }
   public function filterOutputHtml($string) 
    {
        return $this->templateProcessor->filter($string);
    }
```

use `filterOutputHtml()` function in template file

```
<?php
    $collectionTitle = $this->getCollectionTitle();
    ?>
    <div id="element" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": false, "multipleCollapsible": true}}'> 
        <?php foreach ($collectionTitle as $item): ?>  
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <div data-role="trigger"> 
                    <span>
                        <?php echo $block->filterOutputHtml($item->getCategoryName()); ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>    

            <?php $collection = $this->getCollection($item->getId()); ?> 
            <div data-role="content">
                <?php foreach ($collection as $items): ?>             
                    <?php echo $block->filterOutputHtml($items->getQuestion()); ?> 
                    <?php echo $block->filterOutputHtml($items->getAnswer()); ?>            
                <?php endforeach; ?> 
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: working thanks.But why escapeHtml concept is not working here

Comment: escapeHtml Use  in the case of a string output that should not contain HTML.it is not convert into html